# Asp.Net MVC 5 - Favicon

Tags: asp.net, favicon

I Search this Question for all sites, but the examples don't work.
I have this code in the  section, but it isn't working.

```
<link rel="icon" href="@Url.Content("../Images/favicon.ico")" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content("../Images/favicon.ico")" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Any suggestions?!
Thank you!

Comment: "isn't working" is too unspecific. What are you trying to achieve? What happens instead?

Comment: Relative path differs from page to page? Why not use absolute path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this problem and I thought even if the question is old, I should share how i solved it.  I hope it will help someone else.

**The quick fix:**
Delete the `favicon.ico`  that came with the mvc 5 template and replace it with custom icon (which has to be renamed to `favicon.ico`.) The reason for rename is,  by convention browsers looks for favicon at the root of the application.

**Another way:**
Add a `link` inside `head` tag of your html page.

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico"  href="@Url.Content("~/favicon.ico")">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly Give the Path like:-

```
<link rel="icon" href="~/Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```